# Bootstrap navbar vertical not horizontal

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, ssi

I am making a mobile responsive site with Bootstrap 3.3.4. 
I will be making it with server side includes when I can get the web.config file written up since I am using an IIS server.

This is what the nav bar looks like with just the bar. This is what I want it to look like.

Does Bootstrap not like PHP?

http://hurricanetracking.us/nav.html

Other elements on the page. 
http://hurricanetracking.us/new.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hurricane Tracking</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="cat.php">Category Information</a></li> 
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Current
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="Ana.php">Ana</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="Bill.php">Bill</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="Claudette.php">Claudette</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="Danny.php">Danny</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="Erika.php">Erika</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="Fred.php">Fred</a></li>-->
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Historical
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="Ana.php">Ana</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="Bill.php">Bill</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="Claudette.php">Claudette</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="Danny.php">Danny</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="Erika.php">Erika</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="Fred.php">Fred</a></li>-->
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="signup.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="signin.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server and builds an HTML page. The CSS and HTML (I.e. Bootstrap) is rendered on the browser

Comment: Right that is what I though. But it screwed up all of my code after i inserted the bootstrap code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this from index.css

```
.navbar{
background-color:#039;
width:120px;
position:fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
float:left;
}
```

that is what is messing it up!